# Vector dot product calculation wrong sum

Tags: c

I want to make a program that can calculate the vectors with the dot product but  my sum is always 0 what did I do wrong in this code? I'm new to pointers and functions if that is important to you. I coded everything only in the main function and it worked but I want the calculation in another function because its clearer instead of writing everything in the main function. I compiled it with `-Wall` and `-Werror` and I got 0 warnings.

Would be nice if you could help me here :)

Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

double calculation(int o, double *a, double *b, int sum) {
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<o;++i) {
      printf("Components of first vector\n");
      printf("Component %d: ", i+1);
      scanf("%lf", &a[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<o;++i) {
      printf("Components of second vector\n");
      printf("Component %d: ", i+1);
      scanf("%lf", &b[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<o;++i) {
      sum += a[i] * b[i];
    }
    return(0);
}
int main() {

  int o;
  int sum=0;
  printf("How many dimensions should the vectors have?\n");
  scanf("%d", &o);
  double *a = malloc(o * sizeof(double));
  double *b = malloc(o * sizeof(double));
  if(a==NULL) {
    printf("Memoryallocation was not successfull!!!");
    return(1);
  }
  if(b==NULL) {
    printf("Memoryallocation was not successfull!!!");
    return(1);
  }
  calculation(o,a,b,sum);


  printf("The dot product is: %d\n", sum);
  free(a);
  free(b);
  a=NULL;
  b=NULL;


  return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, variables are passed by value. That means that when you change the value of `sum` in `calculation` you only change a local copy.

The idiomatic way when you only need one value is to return it:

```
double calculation(int o, double *a, double *b) {
    double sum = 0.;
    ...
    return sum;
}
```

and in main:

```
...
double sum = calculation(o, a, b);
...
```

Alternatively, if you need to return multiple values, you can pass pointers to the output variables

Answer (score 1):

In `double calculation(int o, double *a, double *b, int sum)` the last argument is passed by value<sup>1</sup>. That is, when you call `calculation(..., sum);`, the variable `sum` is *copied* and then passed to the function.

Inside this function, you're modifying `sum`, but this only modifies the copy of the original variable that was passed. To solve this, pass a pointer or just return the sum from your function.

---

1. Actually, all arguments are passed by value. The second and the third ones just happen to be pointers.

Comment: thank you very much i only returned the sum in the function because its only 1 value and now my program is working :)

Answer (score 0):

This function

```
double calculation(int o, double *a, double *b, int sum) {
```

should change

```
double calculation(int o, double *a, double *b, double & sum) {
```

Comment: The function is returning a `double`. If he were to pass `sum` by reference, then there is no need for return type `double`, it can be `void`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that the `sum` is a local variable in the `calculation` function. So when you return back to main your variable is destructed and the `sum in main` is still 0.

Also if you are getting `floating point values` for `dimensions` then you must use **double for sum** too.

One possible solution could be like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

double calculation(int o, double *a, double *b) {
    int i;
    double sum =0.0;
    for(i=0;i<o;++i) {
      printf("Components of first vector\n");
      printf("Component %d: ", i+1);
      scanf("%lf", &a[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<o;++i) {
      printf("Components of second vector\n");
      printf("Component %d: ", i+1);
      scanf("%lf", &b[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<o;++i) {
      sum += a[i] * b[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
int main() {

  int o;
  double sum =0;
  printf("How many dimensions should the vectors have?\n");
  scanf("%d", &o);
  double *a = malloc(o * sizeof(double));
  double *b = malloc(o * sizeof(double));
  if(a==NULL) {
    printf("Memoryallocation was not successfull!!!");
    return(1);
  }
  if(b==NULL) {
    printf("Memoryallocation was not successfull!!!");
    return(1);
  }
  sum = calculation(o,a,b);


  printf("The dot product is: %lf\n", sum);
  free(a);
  free(b);
  a=NULL;
  b=NULL;


  return(0);
}
```

Or you can pass the address of `sum` to calculation function as:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void calculation(int o, double *a, double *b,double *sum) {
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<o;++i) {
      printf("Components of first vector\n");
      printf("Component %d: ", i+1);
      scanf("%lf", &a[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<o;++i) {
      printf("Components of second vector\n");
      printf("Component %d: ", i+1);
      scanf("%lf", &b[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<o;++i) {
      *sum += a[i] * b[i];
    }
}
int main() {

  int o;
  double sum=0;

  printf("How many dimensions should the vectors have?\n");
  scanf("%d", &o);
  double *a = malloc(o * sizeof(double));
  double *b = malloc(o * sizeof(double));
  if(a==NULL) {
    printf("Memoryallocation was not successfull!!!");
    return(1);
  }
  if(b==NULL) {
    printf("Memoryallocation was not successfull!!!");
    return(1);
  }
  calculation(o,a,b,&sum);


  printf("The dot product is: %lf\n", sum);
  free(a);
  free(b);
  a=NULL;
  b=NULL;


  return(0);
}
```